# Ignoring "The" when sorting an object array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array:

```
var array = {
 "mylist": [
    {
      "item1": "The Ba",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "item1": "Hurts Ama",
      "id": 2
    }
   ]
}
```

and to sort them I am using the following function:

```
function sortByItem(a,b) {
 if (a.item1 < b.item1)
  return -1;
 if (a.item1 > b.item1)
  return 1;
return 0;
}
```

which gives me the output

```
[Hurts Ama, The Ba]
```

However, I don't want "The" to be included when comparing, so that the output would actually be:

```
[Ba, Hurts Ama]
```

Comment: thats an object, not an array.  You have an array as the value for the key `mylist`

Comment: I guess, the initial array is `[ The Ba, Hurts Ama]`, otherwise the current output dissents from the presented object

Comment: In addition to the issue pointed out by @Moose, your variable `array` is not only not an array, its an implicit global. Don't forget the `var`.

Comment: Why do certain elements have an `item1` property while others have an `item2` property? The sorting algorithm won't guarantee that `a` will always be the one with an `item1` property.

Comment: why do you have different property names for comparable content? do you need this? does it follow the pattern of `'item' + id`?

Comment: @NinaScholz my bad, sorry. Edited.

Comment: Sorting `[ {"item1": "The Ba", "id": 1 }, { "item1": "Hurts Ama", "id": 2 } ]` should give `[ {"item1": "The Ba", "id": 1 }, { "item1": "Hurts Ama", "id": 2 } ]` and not `[Ba, Hurts Ama]`.  You should ajust the output in consequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `the` at the beginning with following whitespace.

```js
var array = [{ item1: "The Ba", id: 1 }, { item1: "Hurts Ama", id: 2 }, { item1: "Thereafter ", id: 3 }];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getStripped(s) { return s.replace(/^the\s+/i, ''); }

    return getStripped(a.item1).localeCompare(getStripped(b.item1));
});

console.log(array)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the initial object has keys `"item1"` and `"item2"`, not `"item"`

Comment: @NinaScholz Beautiful solution. Worked perfectly. Many thanks to you and have a great day.

Answer (score -1):

first map a transform function every of your objects that removes any "The " then run your sort by

```
function transform(item) {
   return {
       id: item.id,
       item: item.replace("The ","")
   }
}

var list = 
[
    {
        "item": "The Ba",
        "id": 1
    }, 
    {
        "item": "Hurts Ama",
        "id": 2
    }
]
list.map(transform).sort(sortByItem)
```